# Scala foreach return

Tags: java, scala, foreach, return

How do you make this method work?

```
def filled(b: Board): Board = {
  b.next foreach { n =>
    if (n.filled) n
    else filled(n)
  }
}
```

I need it to return after first filled n (n.filled == true) like in Java.

Now I get:

```
chess-knight.scala:72: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: this.Board
    b.next foreach { n =>
           ^
one error found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Isn't this what you need?

```
def filled(b: Board): Board = b.next find {_.filled} get
```

Providing that `b.next` is a `Seq[Board]` and there is always at least one `filled` `Board`.

If you <del>insist on purely functional</del> prefer an approach exploiting pattern matching over `List`:

```
def filled(b: Board): Board = {
  b.next match {
    case n :: _ if(n.filled) => n
    case _ :: rest => filled(rest)
    case Nil => throw NoSuchElementException
}
```

Comment: What made you think that your first solution wasn't purely functional?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: I mean `List` is defined in terms of `head` and `tail` and pattern matching exploits that fact. One can imagine `filter` being defined in terms of `head` and `tail` as well, so the second approach is using only basic constructs, without helper methods

Comment: Wrong, misleading use of the term "purely functional".

Comment: This is the main problem - filled is (n: Board): Board, not (n: List[Board]): Board and there is not always one filled Board in the branch. This is similar to filling 8x8 chess board with a knight.

Comment: @Etam: OK, I'm a bit lost, there is `filled` method and `filled(b: Board)` method? How are they different? Can you expand your question a little bit?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: The filled(b: Board) method is searching for the first filled Board, it can be checked by b.filled: Boolean method.